# Finding the percentage change in multiple columns

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

If I have a dataframe with two columns, is there a way to compute the percentage change of both the columns in one go? hopefully using the `transform` function

Code to compute percentage change for each column seperately

```
using DataFrames: DataFrame
using ShiftedArrays: lag
 
prices = DataFrame(
  Dict(
   :blue => Float32[8.70,8.91,8.71,8.43,8.73], 
   :orange => [10.66,11.08, 10.71, 11.59, 12.11]
  )
)

prices[:,:pct_blue] = prices.blue ./ lag(prices.blue) .- 1 #5-element vector
prices[:,:pct_orange] = prices.orange ./ lag(prices.orange) .- 1 #5-element vector
```

Instead of this, isnt there a way to do something like this. ofcourse this is incorrect

```
transform!(prices, [:blue, :orange] => x -> x ./ lag(x) .- 1 => [:pct_blue, :pct_orange])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `=>` to `.=>` and placing the function between `()` or `[]` and your code will work.

```
using DataFrames
transform!(prices, [:blue, :orange] .=> (x -> x ./ lag(x) .- 1) .=> [:pct_blue, :pct_orange])
#5×4 DataFrame
# Row │ blue     orange   pct_blue         pct_orange      
#     │ Float32  Float64  Float32?         Float64?        
#─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#   1 │    8.7     10.66  missing          missing         
#   2 │    8.91    11.08        0.024138         0.0393996
#   3 │    8.71    10.71       -0.0224467       -0.0333935
#   4 │    8.43    11.59       -0.0321469        0.0821662
#   5 │    8.73    12.11        0.0355871        0.0448663
```